# Multithreaded TableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I recently got a crash in `UITableViewController`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds for empty array
```

for the code:

```
Message* res = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Where messages is an `NSMutableArray`.

The crash happens because in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I try to get a message from an array of messages, but that array has probably been changed by an other thread. The refreshing of my messages array is done on another thread, which is why I think this happened.

What would be the best way to handle this situation considering that I need to keep using multiple threads?  Is there a way to cancel the drawing of a cell and force the redraw of the entire list of messages? I've tried to do a simple if check:

```
if([messages size] < indexPath.row) {
    return nil;
}
```

That results with the method throwing an assertion exception and crashing the app.

The goal is to gracefully reload the whole view when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multithreading , one must be really careful to switch between background thread and main thread and also at the time of UI Updation . As you are trying to update your UI before thread is completed which result in crash. Let me give you a brief example , firstly we will call a method in background thread

```
[self performSelectorInBackgroungThread:@selector(fetchDataFromServer)
                              withObject:nil
                            onCompletion:nil];
```

Looking on to the other methods

```
-(void)fetchDataFromServer{

  //Some something
  [self performSelectorOnMainthread:@selector(backgroundThreadCompleted)]
                         withObject:nil
                      waitUntilDone:nil]; 
 }
```

Soon after the work in the background thread has been completed I call a method in the Main Thread and perform all the work related to UI Updation in that method only

```
 -(void)backgroundThreadCompleted
 {
      //UI Updation
 }
```

If you follow the same process your application is not going to crash. In your case you are trying to access an empty array(an object at any index that doesn't exist).As a precautionary step iplement a conditional check that if the  [array count]!=0 then only try to access the array else return; . When the values for array changes reload your tableview using [UITableView reloadData].

Comment: I only get the data on the background thread. The messages NSMutableArray is changed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you made changes in your message array you have to reload the tableView.
by using this you message will always be updated on your tableVlew and your crashing problem will resolved